# c# HtmlAgilityPack for on nodes array

Tags: c#, html, arrays, html-agility-pack

I'm using html agility pack and after I got array of nodes:

```
HtmlNode[] nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody[@class='table']").ToArray();
```

now i want to run a for loop one each nodes[i]. I've tried this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {

                if (t == null)
                    t = new Model.Track();

                 HtmlNode[] itemText = nodes[i].SelectNodes("//td[@class='artist']").ToArray();

                for (int x = 0; x < itemText.Length; x++)
                { //doing something      }
```

the problem is that the itemtext array isn't focusing on nodes[i] .
but brings out an array of all the ("//td[@class='artist']") in the html document.
help?

Comment: Can you share the link which you are going to fetch through this or the html?

Comment: i've got the right answer by zroq, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `//td[@class='artist']` will fetch all columns with `artist` class from your `document.DocumentNode`.

Using `.//td[@class='artist']` (Notice the dot at the begining) will fetch all columns with `artist` class from the current selected node, which in your case is `nodes[i]`.